# Masonry items overlap images

Tags: css, wordpress, masonry

If you visit this website (http://www.infismash.com/), you can see that the items are getting overlapped due to the fact that the images are loaded after the page loads.

I'm using the following syntax:

```
<div id="container" class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 0, "itemSelector": ".masonry-content" }' >
    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns masonry-content">
        <article>
        ...
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

This one works well when the images are cached but when the images load after the masonry content is loaded, it overlaps.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The jQuery v1.11.1 is in the header.

I've added the imagesLoaded plugin and now the scripts (in the footer) are like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../masonry.pkgd.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../imagesloaded.pkgd.js'></script>
```

Both of them are called and I'm trying to add masonry on the following:

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns masonry-content">
        <article>
        ...
        </article>
    </div>

    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns masonry-content">
        <article>
        ...
        </article>
    </div>

    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns masonry-content">
        <article>
        ...
        </article>
    </div>

</div>
```

I'm using the following JavaScript to trigger the masonry and imagesLoaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $container = $('#container');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.masonry-content'
      });
    });
</script>
```

This doesn't work.

To put it simply, I've tried to add only the masonry like this:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      $('#container').masonry({
        // options
        itemSelector : '.masonry-content',
        columnWidth : 240
      });
    });    
</script>
```

It doesn't work also.

Any help?

**EDIT**

I have added `class="js-masonry"` `<div id="container">` and now the masonry works but the imagesLoaded is not working. You can check the link provided at the top of this post.

Comment: Was this ever solved? You never reported whether you found a working solution or not. Many of us in StackOverflow would like to know.

Comment: I accepted the answer which worked for me.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait for images to load and than activate `Masonry`. Recommended plugin by David DeSandro (the author) is [imagesloaded](http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/) and the implementation is simple:

var $container = $('#container');

```
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.box'
    });
});
```

You can see the example at [Masonry docs](http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/images.html).

Comment: Why is it a separate plugin now? It used to just be a method that was packaged with masonry.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about this? I can understand that you are telling me to use imagesloaded but how can I integrate that into what I'm using?

Comment: Here is a codepen.io example of him using imagesloaded - http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/kwsJb

Comment: I'm not trying to add images on click. The images are there and it's getting overlapped after loading. I hope I am making you understand. I'm not getting about what code to use to solve this.

Comment: I added a solution for you to check out. I think I have it solved. It does not put "loading spinners" in the blocks to wait for them to load, but I think it works!

Answer (score 1):

Add the imagesloaded plugin found at http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/

I think I have a solution for you. Does this work?

http://codepen.io/tylerism/pen/LVeNKa

HTML

```
<h1>Masonry + imagesLoaded</h1>
<div id="container">
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/300/300" />
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/500/300" />
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/300/500" />
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/300/300" />
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/500/300" />
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/300/500" />
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/300/300" />
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/500/300" />
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/300/500" />
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/300/500" />
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/300/300" />
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/500/300" />
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/300/500" />
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/300/500" />
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/300/300" />
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/500/300" />
  <img class="item" src="http://placebear.com/300/500" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  imagesLoaded('#container', function() {
    var $container = $('#container').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.item',
      columnWidth: 200
    });
  });
});
```

I don't have your exact setup so it is hard for me to test it myself. If this doesn't work we can try something else.

Comment: This doesn't work for me @tylerism. I've edited the question.

Comment: You need to wrap your second to last chunk of code into a document ready. I noticed you left it out. When you say it doesn't work, do you mean it still overlaps?

Comment: Yes. I mean it's still overlapping.